# Ionic: ion-nav-back-button not navigating back

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My problem is, if I use the back button nothing happends. So the idea behind my code is, I want to have on different tabs different views in the side menu. This works without problems. But if I navigate from  /groups to /group/:groupId/:groupName the back button is comming up but if i click on it, it doesn't navigate back to /groups, nothing happends.

Index.html

```
<body ng-app="JasserApp">

<div class="login-main-container" ng-show="showLogin" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <h5>JAPP</h5>
    <div class="login-main-button-container social-wrap b">
        <button class="facebook" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Login with Facebook</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
  The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
-->

<div ng-show="!showLogin" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


</div></body>
```

Tabs.html (I think this is the file with problems)

```
    <ion-side-menus>

    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleRight()"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

        </ion-nav-bar>
        <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
            <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
            <ion-tab title="Groups" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/groups">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-groups"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
            <!-- Chats Tab -->
            <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
            <!-- Account Tab -->
            <!--<ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>-->

        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-nav-view name="sideMenu"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Routing for the views

```
     .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js


  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html',
    controller: 'TabCtrl'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.groups', {
    url: '/groups',
    views: {
      'tab-groups': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-groups.html',
        controller: 'GroupsCtrl'
      },
      'sideMenu':
          {
              templateUrl: 'templates/groups-sideMenu.html',
          }
    }
  })
   .state('tab.group-detail', {
       url: '/group/:groupId/:groupName',
       views: {
          'tab-groups': {
           templateUrl: 'templates/group-detail.html',
           controller: 'GroupsDetailCtrl'
          },
          'sideMenu':
         {
             templateUrl: 'templates/groupDetail-sideMenu.html',
         }
       }
    })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/groups');

});
```

I hope the question is clear.

best regards

Comment: any errors in your console? (viewable using Chrome device inspector or Safari Develop menu)?

Comment: no unluckily not, no error, no warning just a small comment with "cordova :: Native back button handler was detached." But i think this is not the problem, this comments comes while starting the app

Comment: that sounds exactly like something that could be the problem.  If Cordova's back button handler isn't working, then I don't see a reason that Ionic's would, since it sits on top of Cordova.  Any reason why Cordova's handler was detached?

Comment: The message "cordova :: Native back button handler was detached." just appears if i debug in ripple emulator (I think this warning appears because the Emulator doesnt have a native back button), if i debug with Android device this message is not comming but the back button and the native back button do not work.

Comment: it should work. But you can do it manually  by dismissing view